# Как указать в CMake-скрипте для Visual Studio C++ проекте зависимость от Boost.ProgramOptions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake

Пишу проект на C++ с применением `MS Visual Studio 2013`. В проекте у меня используется `Boost.ProgramOptions` для парсинга командной строки. Мне она показалась очень удобной.

Сейчас у меня процесс компиляции проекта выглядит так:

1. Скачиваю архив `boost`-а. Далее распологаю содержимое архива на один уровень выше по отношению к папке с `mercurial`-репозиторием проекта.
2. Компилирую `boost` с помощью [bat](https://bitbucket.org/sys_dev/readpe/raw/7de879d2a4b706ae809229151b744c44bd312124/scripts/boost_compile.cmd) файл(кликабельная ссылка на сам файл)
3. Далее запускаю в студии `sln`-файл и компилирую студией.

Мне нужно упростить этот процесс с помощью применения `CMake`, но у меня нет понимания, а как указать зависимость от `boost` при таком его расположении?

Возможно нужно написать `cmake`-функцию, которая ищет Boost и положить в свой проект и чтобы основной `cmake` скрипт смог применить этот мой кастомный `FindBoost.cmake`.

Также почитал код в `c:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.9\Modules\FindBoost.cmake` и не совсем понял, а сможет ли стандартный скрипт `FindBoost.cmake` найти расположение `boost`-a ? Ведь разархивировать могут абсолютно в *любое* место!

Но есть ли способы лучше?
Возможно я вообще как-то все усложняю и есть подходы лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указывать расположение - это проблема того, кто компилирует ваш проект. Просто используйте FindBoost.cmake, который идёт вместе с CMake.

Comment: Я читал код из `c:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.9\Modules\FindBoost.cmake` и не совсем понял, а сможет ли он найти расположение boost-a. Ведь папку могут расположить в ЛЮБОМ месте!

Comment: Да. Если он не сможет ее найти, он попросит пользователя установить какую-то переменную. `BOOST_DIR` или `BOOST_ROOT`. Пользователь ее установит, и у него все найдется. Вам, как разработчику, заботиться об этом не нужно.

Comment: Из документации к boost-у `The path to the boost root directory (often C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_46_1) is sometimes referred to as $BOOST_ROOT in documentation and mailing lists .` Эти переменные не обязательны!